# Jmapping info box broken ?

Tags: google-maps

I am using jmapping to map several pins on a map in a loop that loops through maybe 50 locations in the U.S.

The issue is that with jmapping, the info box , which is supposed to be like that square comic book style window with a triangle pointing down to the pin, and a shadow for the info-box window itself,  that part is broken when I try to implement it ( see attached photo ) .

I'm using Rails and HAML, but I'm pasting the compiled html code below. This is strange, I spent an entire day trying to figure this out. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Unfortunately, I can't post the url because of NDA rules my company has, but I have posted a screenshot of the issue and the relevant code.

HERE IS A LINK TO THE SCREENSHOT: 
https://plus.google.com/u/0/101306108306543950085/posts/FdirAuN3PNe

Here is my code:

```
 <div class='map-location' data-jmapping='{"id":51,"point":  {"lat":41.47535,"lng":-87.385431},"category":"Gas"}'>
<div class='info-box'>
<div class='vacancy_map_data'>Merrillville , IN</div>
<div class='vacancy_map_data'>Square Feet: 785</div>
<div class='vacancy_map_data'>Monthly Rate: 2650.0</div>
<div class='vacancy_map_data'><a  href="/vacancies/4ffef1ecd0bef8000100003e/vacancy_inquiries/new" class="map-link">Inquire</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem:  There is a conflict with GoogleMaps and Twitter Bootstrap that causes certain graphical elements to misbehave. I solved it by NOT including Twitter Bootstrap on the page in question.